# What should I do when Heroku clear my database after the deployment?

Tags: database, git, heroku

I have had an experience with deployment Web apps with databases on Heroku hosting. When I write `git add .`, `git commit -am "message"` and `git push heroku master`, the batabase of my app is empty. It is so annoying because I lose all the data I had stored in it. How to deal with this?

Comment: Heroku has a backup system for the database. I don't recall if you have to do the backups manually or whether it does so regularly. Check that. Recommendation is that for any valuable data you should have a backup.

Comment: SQLite database? Any idea what is "ephemeral filesystem" at Heroku?

Comment: I'm a bit surprised that pushing your code deleted your data, unless there's something in your code that did it.